# Fastify json-schema-to-ts type provider doesn't work

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I'm trying to implement type inference from JSON schema in Fastify.

This [example from the documentation](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Type-Providers/#json-schema-to-ts) doesn't work for me, as `request.query` remains `unknown` or sometimes `{}`.

Here is a [direct copy-paste of the documentation on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-p2d3nq?file=package.json,index.ts). As you can see the Typescript compilation fails.

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Querystring` type is not defined hence the error. To define it do like the following:

```js
import { JsonSchemaToTsProvider } from '@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts';

import fastify from 'fastify';

const server = fastify().withTypeProvider<JsonSchemaToTsProvider>();

server.get<{ Querystring: { foo: number, bar: string } }>(
  '/route',
  {
    schema: {
      querystring: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          foo: { type: 'number' },
          bar: { type: 'string' },
        },
        required: ['foo', 'bar'],
      },
    } as const, // don't forget to use const !
  },
  (request, reply) => {
    const { foo, bar } = request.query; // type safe!
  }
);
```

Or, to keep it DRY install the `@sinclair/typebox` package and define it beforehand like:

```js
import { JsonSchemaToTsProvider } from '@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts';

import fastify from 'fastify';
import { Static, Type } from '@sinclair/typebox';

const server = fastify().withTypeProvider<JsonSchemaToTsProvider>();

const getQuerystring = Type.Object({
  foo: Type.Number(),
  bar: Type.String(),
})

type GetQuerystring = Static<typeof getQuerystring>

server.get<{ Querystring: GetQuerystring }>(
  '/route',
  {
    schema: {
      querystring: getQuerystring,
    } as const, // don't forget to use const !
  },
  (request, reply) => {
    const { foo, bar } = request.query; // type safe!
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ! yes I saw it works with TypeBox, or we can specify the type explicitely. If there's no way around I guess `@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts` is broken then ..

Comment: Yes, it looks like `@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts` is broken somehow. Although it works on the Typescript Playground, I was never able to make it work on any of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

this solves the issue (:

```
npm i json-schema-to-ts
```